# Do any source code analysis tools detect unused parameters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, code-analysis

How can I detect unused parameters in Ruby?

Options I'm aware of include

- Being rigorous with TDD.
- Heckle (currently works only with Ruby 1.8 due to ParseTree issues)
- Using an IDE such as RubyMine to detect unused parameters or automate the refactoring.

But do any source code analysis tools or warning options allow you to detect unused parameters?

**Background**: I was doing some refactoring. I changed from (code slightly simplified):

```
# Not within the Foo class (therefore can't be as easily accessed by unit testing)
# and in addition, the name of the configuration file is hard-wired
def parse_configuration
  raw_configuration = YAML.load_file("configuration.yml")
  # Do stuff with raw_configuration to produce configuration_options_for_foo
  return configuration_options_for_foo
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  configuration_options_for_foo = parse_configuration
  foo = Foo.new(configuration_options_for_foo)
end
```

to

```
class Foo
  # Now unit tests can call Foo.new_using_yaml("configuration.yml")
  # or use "test_configuration.yml"
  def self.new_using_yaml(yaml_filename)
    # Where I went wrong, forgetting to replace "configuration.yml" with yaml_filename
    raw_configuration = YAML.load_file("configuration.yml")
    # Do stuff with raw_configuration to produce configuration_options_for_foo
    new(configuration_options_for_foo)
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  foo = Foo.new_using_yaml("configuration.yml")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ruby-lint](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/ruby-lint) can detect an unused parameter.

RuboCop has [just added](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (April 2014) detection of unused parameters with the cop "UnusedMethodArgument".

Answer (score 1):

I think Laser does this.

It's pretty alpha-y, but seems to do what you want.

http://github.com/michaeledgar/laser

Answer (score 0):

[Reek](https://github.com/troessner/reek) can [detect unused parameters](https://github.com/troessner/reek/wiki/Unused-Parameters).